# Need MySQL query using left join which displays null for duplicate data on left

Tags: mysql, join, null

(Simplified)

In a table PET_TYPES the columns are id, type

In a table PET_NAMES the columns are id, type_id, pet_name

The basic query is:

```
select pt.*, pn.pet_name from PET_TYPES pt left join PET_NAMES pn on pt.id=pn.type_id
```

I need for display purposes, however, to show NULL for all duplicate values on the left. Instead of:

```
id |  type      |  pet_name

1  |  aardvark  |  NULL
2  |  dog       |  Charlie
3  |  dog       |  Rover
4  |  cat       |  Tabby
5  |  cat       |  Sandy
6  |  cat       |  MeowMeow
```

I need:

```
id |  type      |  petname

1  |  aardvark  |  NULL
2  |  dog       |  Charlie
3  |  NULL      |  Rover
4  |  cat       |  Tabby
5  |  NULL      |  MeowMeow
6  |  NULL      |  Sandy
```

TIA

Comment: Do that in your program logic. SQL is not designed for this.

Comment: MySQL can handle this task using in-line variable assignment.

Comment: but what is your original data to determine / result as you have it.

Comment: DRapp, the first table is registrants for a trade show, the second table is their guests. The organizers want an Excel export and are confused by multiple registrant values but still need to know which guests are associated with each registrant. Some registrants are not bringing guests.

Comment: can you provide the sample data for us to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a variable and an IF, as follows:

```
SELECT id,
       IF(type=@prev,NULL,@prev:=type) AS type,
       petname
  FROM (
            select pt.*, pn.pet_name 
              from PET_TYPES pt
         left join PET_NAMES pn on pt.id=pn.type_id
       ) AS list,
  (SELECT @prev:='') AS init
 ORDER BY list.type, list.id
```

Notice how your query is wrapped up in an outer one.

The IF statement suppresses the consecutive duplicates.

Comment: Ollie, thanks for your answer. This does work for my limited example and will probably serve, although the actual table being represented by PET_TYPES has about 15 columns which need to be suppressed after the first listing. It seems last year I had a more elegant solution and have forgotten it, which is my own &!$#@ fault.

Comment: You can build out this trick to suppress repeated values in multiple columns. But it's brittle and a pain in the neck to debug. You may want to consider figuring out how to do this report formatting in your client code (Java, php, PERL, whatever).